# java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: ACCES denied for user 'Name'@localhost' ( using passwprd : NO )

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx

I have an airline system mangement project where I work with multiple databases.
The first one ( db ) works fine.
When I try to implement the second one i got an 'access denied' message.

I copy-pasted the code from the first one but I replaced the name of the first database with the name of the second one as you can see and I changed the column names for the specific table.

Can someone help me with this one?
I tried adding `skip-grant-tables` into my.ini ) '

```
package sample.my_project_uvt;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class MySqlConnectPassengers {
enter code here
    Connection conn = null;
    public  static  Connection ConnectDb(){

        try {
        
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/passengers");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ConnectionEstablished");
            return conn;


        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static ObservableList<passengers> getDatauser(){


        Connection conn = ConnectDb();
        ObservableList<passengers>list= FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try{

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `passengers`;");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                list.add(new passengers(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ID")),rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("EMAIL"),rs.getString("FLIGHT_ID"),rs.getString("PHONE")));

            }

        }catch (Exception e )
        {

        }


        return list;
    }

}




package sample.my_project_uvt;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Passagers_controller implements Initializable {

    public Passagers_controller(){

    }
    @FXML
    private Button buttonMenu;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonBook;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<passengers, String> col_email;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<passengers, String> col_flight;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<passengers, Integer> col_id;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<passengers, String> col_name;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<passengers, String> col_phone;

    @FXML
    private TableView<passengers> table_users;

    ObservableList<passengers> listM;

    int index = -1;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;


    @FXML
    public void userChangeBook(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        HelloApplication m = new HelloApplication();
        m.changeScene("Book.fxml");

    }
    public void userChangeMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        HelloApplication m = new HelloApplication();
        m.changeScene("MENU.fxml");

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<passengers,Integer>("ID"));
        col_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<passengers,String>("NAME"));
        col_email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<passengers,String>("EMAIL"));
        col_flight.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<passengers,String>("FLIGHT_ID"));
        col_phone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<passengers,String>("PHONE"));

        listM=MySqlConnectPassengers.getDatauser();
        table_users.setItems(listM);

    }
}



package sample.my_project_uvt;

public class passengers {

    int ID;
    String NAME, EMAIL, FLIGHT_ID,PHONE;

    public passengers(int ID, String NAME, String EMAIL, String FLIGHT_ID, String PHONE) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL;
        this.FLIGHT_ID = FLIGHT_ID;
        this.PHONE = PHONE;
    }

    public int getID() {return ID;}

    public String getNAME() {return NAME;}

    public String getEMAIL() {return EMAIL;}

    public String getFLIGHT_ID() {return FLIGHT_ID;}

    public String getPHONE() {return PHONE;}

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setNAME(String NAME) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
    }

    public void setEMAIL(String EMAIL) {
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL;
    }

    public void setFLIGHT_ID(String FLIGHT_ID) {
        this.FLIGHT_ID = FLIGHT_ID;
    }

    public void setPHONE(String PHONE) {
        this.PHONE = PHONE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On DriverManager.getConnection you should also provide a name and password for the user you want to connect with. This user must have credentials to connect from that host your programm is running on.
Example: `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(   "jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<schema>","username","password");`  
Edit:
A very good guideline can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)